# Have there ever been a work of fiction in which a Unicorn is portrayed as Evil/bad etc.?

Tags: fantasy-genre, unicorns

Unicorns are typically treated as pure, virtuous and innocent creatures...

So, are there any instances of a Unicorn behaving in a manner that is the complete opposite of that expected of it? I.e, if it could talk; expressing vulgar or uncouth behaviour, or teaming with the enemy/ behaving in a generally antagonistic way?

Comment: are you familiar with the youtube series [Charlie the Unicorn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZu3P0OsQPk) ?

Comment: This doesn't count as antagonistic, but unicorns from the _Witcher_ books were at war with the Aen Elle elves (essentially the Wild Hunt elves) when the latter invaded the former's homeworld.

Comment: The cartoon Gravity Falls had at least one unicorn that was a real jerk.

Comment: Does Robot chicken's portrayal of unicorns count?

Comment: @CBredlow - Or [South Park](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNGgfpjNHs4&feature=youtu.be&t=3m41s) :-)

Comment: Charles Stross' unicorns are decidedly not nice - [Equoid](http://www.tor.com/2013/09/24/equoid/)

Comment: [Unicorns being jerks](https://www.amazon.com/Unicorns-Are-Jerks-Coloring-Exposing/dp/1477468528)

Comment: [There is now](http://pastebin.com/fNh1n0sh). Warning, uncouth language detected

Comment: While this seems like a recommendation to me, there is an excellent example in [Rampant](https://www.amazon.com/Rampant-Diana-Peterfreund-ebook/dp/B002LUHZ5K/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1472242980&sr=1-1&keywords=rampant) and associated books, by Diana Peterfreund. In this series, unicorns are generally bloodthirsty killing machines. The best of them are either animalistic and violent or highly antisocial, and the worst are downright malicious.

Comment: Tlingel, the unicorn in Roger Zelazny's ["Unicorn Variation"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40831). Hangs out in saloons, plays chess, guzzles beer; intends to destroy humanity but agrees to spare us if the human character can beat it in a game of chess.